# Spring: apply @Autowired to property to eliminate setter

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired, xml-configuration

My understanding about the @Autowired annotation applying on a property of a bean is that by doing that we can eliminate the setter method. This seems valid when we choose to annotation based configuration: we just create a bean annotated with @Component and annotate @Autowired to its property of interest.

However I failed to do the same when I tested the idea using xml based configuration.

Here is what I put in the bean class:

```
@Autowired
private String message2;

public String getMessage2() {
    return message2;
}
```

In the xml file:

```
<bean id="testBean" class="TestBean">
    <property name="message2" value="Hello world!"/>
</bean>
```

the IDE complained "can't resolve the property" and failed to compile. Maybe using @Autowired with xml configuration is an odd marriage that is disallowed?

Anyone care to help me on this might-be-silly question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the setter, then get rid of the `<property>` element in your `TestBean` bean definition. That `property` requires that a setter be available to set the property. Because it's missing, if you actually tried to load the XML configuration, with a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` for example, you'd get this error

> Caused by: `org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException`: Invalid property `message2` of bean class [`org.example.TestBean`]: Bean property `message2` is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

After removing `<property>`, declare an appropriate bean to inject

```
<bean id="message2" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg value="Helllo world!"/>
</bean>
```

You'll also need

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

to register the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` that handles processing of `@Autowired`.

---

Note that declaring a `String` bean is awkward. You'd be better served by using the `<property>` or some property resolution mechanism that pulls the value from a config file and assigns it through a `@Value` annotated field.

```
@Value("${config.message2}")
private String message2;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response. The code smells (and won't work as pointed out) but I just experimented to test some ideas such as 1) how xml config work with @Autowired, and 2) what it means by "eliminating setters when using autowired on property".

Comment: @J.E.Y Yeah, I originally misunderstood your question and had to edit my answer. But, yeah, the point is, if you remove the setter, you can't use `<property>`.